# Android: table sql query error

Tags: android, sql, contacts

I am trying to send query to contacts database:

```
String CONTACTS = "/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db";
SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
try{
   sqlDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(CONTACTS,null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}catch(SQLiteException sqlE){
   Log.e(TAG, sqlE.getMessage());
}
callCursor = sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id, date, duration, number, type, name, numbertype,  COUNT(*) as cnt FROM calls WHERE ( 1=1 ) GROUP BY (number) ORDER BY cnt DESC", null);
```

But I get the error

```
05-04 15:21:28.271: E/SQLiteDatabase(883): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
```

What is the reason?

Comment: It is crashs before SQL query on sqlDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(CONTACTS,null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

Comment: Yes I know, so I think you have two problems: one is that you can't connect, and the second is that even if you do connect, your query is wrong so it still won't work.

Comment: This SQL query allready was used. Even I must using qb.query(SQLiteDatabase db, CALL_LOG_GROUP_PROJECTION, "_id = _id", null, Calls.NUMBER, null, "_id DESC") but and here i must have SQLiteDatabase.

Answer (score 1):

String CONTACTS = "/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db"; should be String CONTACTS = "/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db";